# How do i create popover on a toolbar button in Firefox with extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul, toolbar, popover

I'm developing extension for firefox which needs to show popover with html document. In Safari and Chrome there is pretty straightforward way to create popover, but as for now i spent 2 days looking for a way to do the same thing in Firefox, but i could not find a page in documentation for doing that.

Can someone provide me with sample of code, link to tutorial or documentation i would be very grateful.

Here is the image of the popover in Safari
[image]

Comment: Are you using the add-on SDK, or are you creating a XUL based add-on?

Comment: I was not aware that there is a thing like SDK, i was using XUL based add on.

Answer (score 3):

In a xul based addon, that can be accomplished with a panel. If you see [the page for the type property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Attribute/panel.type) of a panel, they have something similar to what you want.

[image]

What you would do is:

```
<toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
      <toolbarbutton id="yourToolbarbutton"
                       image="chrome://yourExt/content/image.png"
                       class="toolbarbutton-1 chromeclass-toolbar-additional">
            <panel id="yourPanel"
                       type="arrow"
                       noautofocus="true"
                       consumeoutsideclicks="true"
                       onpopupshowing="functionToFillThePanel();"
                       level="top">

                   content goes here
             </panel>
     </toolbarbutton>
/toolbarpalette>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find this at this tutorials

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/School_tutorial

Comment: That's the first place i visited, but didn't managed to find what i was looking for.